# Tool for Automatic Removal of `using namespace`

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-format

Is there any tool to convert:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace foo;
using namespace bar;

namespace foo
{
  int foo_value() { return 5; }
}

namespace bar
{
  const double bar_var = 3;
  double bar_value() { return 2*bar_var; }
}

int main () {
  cout << foo_value() << '\n';
  cout << bar_var     << '\n';
  cout << bar_value() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

to

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo
{
  int foo_value() { return 5; }
}

namespace bar
{
  const double bar_var = 3;
  double bar_value() { return 2*bar_value; }
}

int main () {
  std::cout << foo::foo_value() << '\n';
  std::cout << bar::bar_var     << '\n';
  std::cout << bar::bar_value() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I want to remove `using namespace` and use the full name for the functions and variables for each namespace.

Visual Studio Intellisense has code completion and I wanted to see if it can automatically replace for example `foo_value()` with  `foo::foo_value()` in the source code. If not, is there any tool with such capabilities? The provided example is just to explain the question. In fact, I have a project with multiple source/header files, which I would like to use the tool for.

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388469/is-there-a-working-c-refactoring-tool

Comment: Facing the same problem, did you found a solution?